# JQuery script loading before DOM is completed on Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

I believe that is the issue I am having.  I keep running into an 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' error on either classes or IDs that JQuery is looking for within the DOM.  I'm attempting to have the top div/title of the Add2Any menu close the menu.  I'm sure there are other problems with my click function, but I believe my problems lies within the ID I need (#a2apage_DEFAULT) to target not being loaded yet.  I've tried having the script called in both the Module's info file in question, and through the theme's info file with no luck.  I get the first alert, and then looking in dev tools, I see Uncaught TypeError on #a2apage_DEFAULT.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    Drupal.behaviors.cee = {
        attach: function(context, settings){
            console.log("attach");
            $('#a2apage_DEFAULT').click(function() {
                console.log("click");
                $(this).parent('#a2apage_dropdown').css('display','none');
            })
        }
    };
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: Since I can't add pictures due to my reputation level, here is an external link to what the errors look like on my dev tools. http://imgur.com/YRNatzG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, the error probably relates to your use of `$`, without having assigned anything to that variable.

This should work:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cee = {
    attach: function(context, settings){
      console.log("attach");
        $('#a2apage_DEFAULT').click(function() {
          console.log("click");
          $(this).parent('#a2apage_dropdown').css('display','none');
        })
      }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm just learning JQuery and JS. This fixed my issue and I was able to complete what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You should be waiting for document to load and not for window

```
jQuery(document).load(function () {
    Drupal.behaviors.cee = {
        attach: function(context, settings){
            console.log("attach");
            $('#a2apage_DEFAULT').click(function() {
                console.log("click");
                $(this).parent('#a2apage_dropdown').css('display','none');
            })
        }
    };
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: This is what my code looks like now.  Is the ending syntax correct? I still receive the same error at the ID.
jQuery(document).load(function () {
    Drupal.behaviors.cee = {
        attach: function(context, settings){
            console.log("attach");
            $('#a2apage_DEFAULT').click(function() {
                console.log("click");
                $(this).parent('#a2apage_dropdown').css('display','none');
            })
        }
    };
} (jQuery));

Comment: You also need to make sure drupal core files are loaded before you use this function, you can try `console.log(Drupal);` before attaching event to make sure drupal object exists

Comment: In normal jQuery land this is correct...in Drupal, not so much. `Drupal.behaviors.cee.attach()` is only invoked on DOM ready anyway

Comment: @Clive must be right, your 'attach' is fired so it must be $, try swapping $ with jQuery

Comment: Thanks for both of your help, that was the problem.